# Sentence agreement

Tags: sentence, sentence-fragments

"Imagine building, designing, and planning your own house would be great right?"

What is the problem in the sentence? It doesn't agree with the subject verb agreement. Help please!

Comment: 'It doesn't agree with the subject verb agreement' seems to be derived from some source. Can you link to this, Lony? There are different ways to 'correct this sentence'. (eg "Imagine designing and building your own house ... that would be great, right?" But if you don't **clearly** explain the problem you have, it's off-topic here.

Comment: There's a valid "imperative" sentence: *Imagine building, designing, and planning your own house* here. ***And*** a valid "tag question" assertion: *[building, designing, and] planning your own house would be great, right?* But the string of words between ***Imagine*** and ***would be great*** can't simultaneously serve as the object of the first utterance ***and*** the subject of the second.

Comment: First off, it's more idiomatic to list the actions in chronological order.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. It's supposed to be a question, but it's not possible to pronounce it with question intonation because it's missing its subject and some punctuation.